# Set Default template for category page in Magento

Tags: magento

New to Magento.

Can any one guide me how to define a default layout for category pages.

Tried local.xml in my theme folder but not working.

Here is my xml file :-

```
<!-- Default handle, loaded on most pages -->
<default>

    <reference name="head">

        <!-- Remove Magento's default assets -->
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/print.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/styles-ie.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/styles.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_css</type>
            <name>css/widgets.css</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/ie6.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>varien/menu.js</name>
        </action>

        <!-- Add our assets -->
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/font-awesome.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/jquery-ui.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>dist/css/style.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/ddSlick.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/parsjewellers.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery-ui.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/ddSlick_jquery.dropdown.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>dist/js/script.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/my_site.js</name>
        </action>

        <!-- Add additioanl child blocks -->
        <block type="core/template" name="boilerplate.head.meta" template="boilerplate/page/html/head/meta.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/template" name="boilerplate.head.ie8" template="boilerplate/page/html/head/ie8.phtml"/>

    </reference>

    <reference name="header">
        <block type="directory/currency" name="custom_currency_selector" template="currency/currency.phtml"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="right">
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo" />
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout" />
        <remove name="right.poll" />
        <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <remove name="currency" />
        <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
        <remove name="tags_popular" />
        <remove name="left.newsletter" />
    </reference>

</default>

<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>


<print>

    <reference name="head">

        <!-- Add our assets -->
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/script-ck.js</name>
        </action>

    </reference>

</print>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was using layered navigation and my xml update was overwritten by 
catalog_category_layered handle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 9):

Changing individual category page layout

You can modify the page layout of each individual category by the following steps:

```
 1. Go to Catalog -> Manage Categories
 2. Select any category
 3. Click the 'Custom Design' tab
 4. Select your desired page layout from 'Page Layout' selectbox
 5. Save Category and you are done!
```

Changing category page from your **local.xml** file:

```
 1. Open layout/local.xml file
 2. Find the node 'catalog_category_default' and add

<catalog_category_default>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Another method:

```
 1. Open layout/page.xml file
 2. Under the ‘default’ node, you will find the following code

<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml">
```

The above line has set **2columns-left** layout. You can change it to your desired choice like **2columns-right**, **3columns**, etc.

P.S: If you are using layered navigation, you need to use `<catalog_category_layered>` node to change the layout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.


The first method is not an option for me

That's why i already tried the second method 

<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

As you can see in my question. But dont know why thats not working.

Comment: Enable template path hints on your category page and see which layout is being called

Comment: Solved the issue.
My xml update was overwridden by
catalog_category_layered present in layered navigation.